# How to get LinkedIn member data using profile URL?

Tags: web-scraping, linkedin-api

I am trying to build a service to get profile data(Education, Experience, Skills etc.) of a LinkedIn user using profile URL.
I do not want to use any LinkedIn developer APIs.

One of the solution I have come across is using Selenium and BeautifulSoup library where I need to login and parse the html page but LinkedIn can block my IP in such cases.

I want to scale my service to thousands of hits in a month.

What could be the other alternatives to achieve this? Is it possible to do this without login?